# rendering navbar conditional, whe converting to dropdown in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a navigation bar, from a bootstrap theme, that i use in react

It works that there is an in built media-query, that termniates rather it's a dropdown or not with a toggler to handle the dropdown

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" onClick={this.onToggleNav} data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

i then render the content of the navbar conditionally

```
<div className={this.state.navClosed ? "navbar-collapse " : "navbar-collapse collapse"} id="navbarColor01" >
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

my issue is that, when the screen is at full length, the items are only shown is the navClosed state is sat to true, so, if It's false, the content will not be shown, unless the screen is put to a lower width, and the toggle button shows.

I was wondering if you could make some sort of lifeCycleHook or conditional handler, to check the width of the screen, and then set the state, if the width, reached a certain breakpoint

```
  state = {
navClosed: false,
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If it is [supported by your browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver) one solution would be to use the Resize Observer API.

You can add something like this to your component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const navClosedWidth = 600;
    let {ResizeObserver} = window;
    let observer = new ResizeObserver(([{contentRect: rect}]) => {
        let navWidth = rect.width;
        if(this.state.navClosed && (navWidth > navClosedWidth)) {
            this.setState({navClosed: false});
        } else if(!this.state.navClosed && (navWidth <= navClosedWidth)) {
            this.setState({navClosed: true});
        }
    });
    observer.observe(document.querySelector("html"));
}
```

Which will update the state when the width hits a certain threshold.

[Resize Observer documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver)